# Non return with Iloc. IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm doing a loop that looks in one dataframe (exp_df) to find and add the data 'Experience Type' in duty_df, IF there is rows with the same criterias that in duty_df (Date, User ID and Experience Type).

I get the return:

```
"IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0".
```

I think the problem is that not all exp_df searches are going to return any answer, then I want it to loop to the next.

I tried an If function with the same ILOC statment, but got the same fault code.

```
    for t in range(0, len(duty_df)):
        duty_df['Ara'] = exp_df.loc[(exp_df['User Id'] == duty_df['User Id'][t]) & 
        (exp_df['Experience Type'] == 'ARA(Rig)') & (exp_df['From Date'] == 
        duty_df['Duty Date'][t])]['Experience Type'].values[0]
```

Row 2,3 and 4 is on the same line, but if didn't fit here.

Any ideas?

Update:

exp_df:

```
  User Id   From Date Aircraft Type      Experience Type  Quantity
   793  2020-06-18          S92A            Precision         1
  1793  2020-07-13          S92A             ARA(Rig)         1
  1793  2020-07-27          S92A             ARA(Rig)         1
  1793  2020-08-11          S92A            Precision         1
  1793  2020-08-25          S92A            Precision         1
```

duty_df:

```
  User Id            Duty Date  ... Total Duty Minutes Total FDP Minutes
  1793     2020-04-03 00:00:00  ...              490.0             475.0
  1793     2020-04-04 00:00:00  ...              310.0             295.0
  1793     2020-04-08 00:00:00  ...              435.0             420.0
  1793     2020-04-09 00:00:00  ...              430.0             415.0
  1793     2020-04-17 00:00:00  ...              540.0             365.0
```

Comment: Not so clear. Can you show a snippet of ``exp_df`` or whatever df where this IndexError persist?

Comment: Index Row: [User Id, From Date, Aircraft Type, Experience Type,  Quantity]. Row one: [1793,  2020-06-18, S92A, Precision, 1]

Comment: Add it to your question please,  you can't format it in comment

Comment: You can't do this as a oneliner.  You need to check if your comparisons return something or not.

Comment: Do you actually mean ``&``? Bitwise operator? Not a normal the word ``and``?